# Collapse data by ID in data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, aggregate

I am try to collapse data by ID and Gender.
I have the data frame:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
Gender <- c("M","M","M","M","F","F",'F',"F","F","F", "M", "M", "M")
Test1 <- c("70", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "85", "NA", "NA", "90", "NA", "NA", "NA", "90")
Test2 <- c("NA", "60", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "82", "NA", "NA", "87", "NA", "88", "NA")

df <- data.frame(ID, Gender, Test1, Test2)

   ID Gender Test1 Test2
1   1      M    70    NA
2   1      M    NA    60
3   1      M    NA    NA
4   1      M    NA    NA
5   2      F    NA    NA
6   2      F    85    NA
7   2      F    NA    82
8   3      F    NA    NA
9   3      F    90    NA
10  3      F    NA    87
11  4      M    NA    NA
12  4      M    NA    88
13  4      M    90    NA
```

I am hoping to get help on how to collapse the data across ID and Gender so I can have 1 row per ID. Which would look like this:

```
  id gender test1 test2
1  1      M    70    60
2  2      F    85    82
3  3      F    90    87
4  4      M    90    88
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do if there are more than 1 non NA value for an ID?  What have you tried so far?  Are you looking to do something like `df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  summarise_all(min)`

Comment: This is what I tried so far: df_new <- df[,lapply(.SD, paste0, collapse = , by = ("ID", "Gender"))]    but it did not work I will try you code and see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# convert the type from factor to integer
# this step is not necessary if you create these columns of type integer
df$Test1 <- as.integer(as.character(df$Test1))
df$Test2 <- as.integer(as.character(df$Test2))

# choose non-NA value for each (ID, gender) combination
# the function max is interchangeable, you just need the NA treatment 
df %>%
  group_by(ID, Gender) %>%
  summarise(
    Test1 = max(Test1, na.rm = T),
    Test2 = max(Test2, na.rm = T)
  )

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
# # Groups:   ID [?]
#      ID Gender Test1 Test2
#   <dbl> <fct>  <int> <int>
# 1     1 M         70    60
# 2     2 F         85    82
# 3     3 F         90    87
# 4     4 M         90    88
```

With some type adjustments:

```
# create the example data with suitable column types
df <- data_frame(
  ID = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2:4, each = 3)),
  Gender = c(rep("M", 4), rep("F", 6), rep("M", 3)),
  Test1 = c(70, rep(NA, 4), 85, rep(NA, 2), 90, rep(NA, 3), 90),
  Test2 = c(NA, 60, rep(NA, 4), 82, rep(NA, 2), 87, NA, 88, NA)
)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, Gender) %>%
  summarise(
    Test1 = max(Test1, na.rm = T),
    Test2 = max(Test2, na.rm = T)
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I made one edit to your data by adding `stringAsFactors = FALSE` to your `data.frame` argument. Let me know if this solution works for you:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                 Gender = c("M","M","M","M","F","F",'F',"F","F","F", "M", "M", "M"),
                 Test1 = c("70", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "85", "NA", "NA", "90", "NA", "NA", "NA", "90"),
                 Test2 = c("NA", "60", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "82", "NA", "NA", "87", "NA", "88", "NA"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

new_df <- df %>%
          gather(key = "test_num", value = "score", Test1, Test2)%>%
          filter(score != "NA")%>%
          spread(test_num, score)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which will paste together values from Test1 and Test2. This will work even if you have multiple genders and values for Test1 and Test2, but will leave the values as factors.

```
df$Test1 <- as.integer(as.character(df$Test1))
df$Test2 <- as.integer(as.character(df$Test2))

xy <- sapply(split(df, f = df$ID), FUN = function(x) {
  out <- data.frame(ID = unique(x$ID),
                    Gender = paste(unique(x$Gender), collapse = ", "),
                    Test1 = paste(unique(na.omit(x$Test1)), collapse = ","),
                    Test2 = paste(unique(na.omit(x$Test2)), collapse = ","))
  out
}, simplify = FALSE)

xy <- do.call(rbind, xy)

  ID Gender Test1 Test2
1  1      M    70    60
2  2      F    85    82
3  3      F    90    87
4  4      M    90    88
```